# How do I order by node depth and then by tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an HTML form that's built dynamically using templates at runtime - dictated by user action.

I need to set the tab index across the form based on the tabindexing specified within each of the pieces of the form.

Given this, is there a way in jQuery to order items within a set? For instance something that follows this pseudo structure would be awesome, but I can't figure out how to achieve it:

```
<div name="firstTemplate" templateIndex="0">
    <input type="text" name="field0" tabIndex="1" />
    <input type="text" name="field1" tabIndex="2" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" tabIndex="3" />
</div>
<div name="firstTemplateRpt" templateIndex="1">
    <input type="text" name="field0" tabIndex="1" />
    <input type="text" name="field1" tabIndex="2" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" tabIndex="3" />
</div>
<div name="secondTemplate" templateIndex="2">
    <input type="text" name="field0" tabIndex="1" />
    <input type="text" name="field1" tabIndex="2" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" tabIndex="3" />
</div>
```

I could then use some variation of the following concept:

```
$("input, textarea, select, input:checkbox, input:radio").orderBy("templateIndex, tabIndex");
```

Where templateIndex would be the index of the template within the form and the tabindex would be the tabindex of the control within the template. A template could be added to the form multiple times at runtime, which is causing havoc on manually specified tabindexes.

When another template is added to the form, it would be assigned the templateIndex="3" with its manually set tabIndexes starting again at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the divs with a *templateIndex* attribute into an array, then sort them like:

```
divArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('templateIndex') - b.getAttribute('templateIndex');
});
```

Then iterate over those and sort the inputs inside the array using a very similar function:

```
inpArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.tabIndex - b.tabIndex;
});
```

Then move the elements in the required order in the document using something like *node.parentNode.insertBefore(node, firstChild)*.

Comment: I think you've got the crux of it, I'll try that. I don't want to move the fields in the document, I just want to adjust the tabindexes so that they run in sequence from 1 to *n*, where *n* is the number of fields. I think what you've given me will help me get there though, thanks.

Comment: Ok, then you just need to iterate over the the nodes and add properties based on the loop counter. You can use collections for that, or a recursive walk down the DOM for unlimited (or defined but variable) depth. Whatever suits.